# No puedo usar una variable global en el main c++

Tags: c++, variables-globales

**Clase.h:**

```
class Clase{
...
}
```

**Clase.cpp:**

```
#include "Clase.h"
int var_global;
...
```

**Main.cpp:**

```
#include "Clase.h"
#include <iostream>
...
std::cout<<var_global<<std::endl;
...
```

## El Problema

A la hora de utilizar la variable en el `main`, el compilador me avisa que esa variable no ha sido declarada, la he intentado declarar en **Clase.cpp** pero me sale que hay definiciones múltiples, así que mi duda es como puedo mantener esa variable para que pueda utilizarse tanto en el `main` como en la definición de la clase.

Comment: Para evitar las definiciones múltiples podrías usar "include-guards": `#ifndef-#define-#endif`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casi lo tienes.

C++ no compila los archivos de cabecera (`*.h`), los copia-pega en archivos de código (`*.cpp`) que sí son compilados. Cada archivo de código crea una [Unidad de Traducción](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) (UdT) y en cada UdT aparecen símbolos que pueden ser propios o de otras UdT, el [enlazador](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enlazador) se encargará de hacer que los símbolos de otras UdT estén disponibles en las UdT propias para generar el programa final.

Cada vez que en un archivo de cabecera se define un símbolo (por ejemplo tu `class Clase{...}`) estás haciendo que el símbolo se defina de la misma manera en todos los archivos de código en que incluyas dicha cabecera, dando lugar a varias UdT con el mismo símbolo definido y esto está prohibido en C++ por la [regla de definición única](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule), por eso el compilador te avisa de que hay definiciones múltiples.

#### Solución.

Para empezar usa una [guarda de inclusión](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) en tu `Clase.h`:

`Clase.h`

```
#ifndef NOMBRE_UNICO
#define NOMBRE_UNICO

class Clase{
    ...
}

#endif
```

Seguidamente declara `var_global` como externa en `Main.cpp`

`Main.cpp`

```
#include "Clase.h"
#include <iostream>

extern int var_global;

...
std::cout<<var_global<<std::endl;
...
```

Por la regla de definición única indicada anteriormente no puedes volver a definir `var_global` en `Main.cpp` pero si la marcas como `extern` le estás diciendo al compilador "*este símbolo existe, pero su definición está en otro lado*", cuando el enlazador busque el símbolo `var_global` buscará la definición que no sea externa y la usará.

La norma para usar `extern` es que puedes tener un símbolo declarado como `extern` tantas veces como quieras pero una y sólo una declaración no debe ser externa.